# h:dataTable getter called despite rendered="false"

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I have dataTable whose getter gets called when it shouldn't. We're using JSF 2.2.6 with CDI.

Here's the part from the xthml file:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="false">
    <h:dataTable id="someObjectTable" border="0" width="900"
        value="#{SomeController.someObjects}"
        rowClasses="odd, even" var="value" columnClasses="formLeft, formRight"
        listHeight="">

    </h:dataTable>
</h:panelGroup>
```

And here's the bean:

```
public List<SomeObject> getSomeObjects(){
    //... ... ...
    return resutList;
}
```

Even though the panelGroup around the dataTable has its rendered set to false, getSomeObjects gets called. Why is that? Should it really be called even though it will not be rendered?

Comment: Is the `xmlns:h` properly declared in template? If so, please edit question to include single result of `Thread.dumpStack()` call in getter so we can see who's calling it and why.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but a litte bit tricky.

Try to use jstl tag

```
<c:if test="#{renderCondition}">
    <h:dataTable id="someObjectTable" border="0" width="900"
        value="#{SomeController.someObjects}"
        rowClasses="odd, even" var="value" columnClasses="formLeft,formRight"
    listHeight="">
    </h:dataTable>
</c:if>
```

Comment: why tricky? And keep in mind that you can in this case not ever make it rendered anymore with an ajax update

Comment: Yeah you're right, it cannot be rendered with an ajax update unless it's not updated from outside. In my project I updated it from outside that's why I didn't see that.